# jQuery: Adding attribute and including href value

Tags: jquery

I'd like to check if a link doesn't contain part of a URL, and if so, add an 'onclick' attribute (for Analytics tracking). I can do this but can't figure out how to add the actual link's href into the new attribute.

For example, if I want to only target links that don't contain 'example.com', I can do this:

```
$('a:not([href*="example.com"])').attr("onclick","_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','clickout-see-also','web','www.blah.com']);");
```

How can I replace 'www.blah.com' with the actual href value? I guess it's related to `this.href` but can't get this working...I tried the following but just got `undefined`:

```
$('a:not([href*="example.com"])').attr("onclick","_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','clickout-see-also','web'," + $(this).attr('href') + "]);");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the receiver function of `.attr()` to achieve what you want,

```
$('a:not([href*="example.com"])').attr("onclick", function(){
  return "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','clickout-see-also','web','" + $(this).attr('href') + "']);"
});
```